# How can I dump bitbucket environment variables into a file?

Tags: bitbucket

I have a service that will be migrated to Github, But before moving forward I need to dump the bitbucket repo environment variables into a local file. Is that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by using `Bitbucket API`. You can `list` variables and `get` each variable via `cURL`, `bash script` or some languages like `Python`, `Java`, `Node.js` or `PHP`.

API documentation references :

**list :** https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pipelines/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-pipelines-config-variables-get

**get :** https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pipelines/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-pipelines-config-variables-variable-uuid-get